# Use icons for polygons based on Boolean values from attribute table as secondary symbology

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, classification, icon

I have a multypolygon-shapefile of government districts in Germany with two columns, "population density" and "yesno":
The first has integer the second one Boolean values.
I have already colored the map using the population density values (`Symbology` - `graduated`).
Now I'd like to use the second column (yesno) for symbology as well.
I want to put one of two symbols (one for `true` and one for `false`) on every government district.
I know how to use icons for points, but not for polygons.
And I know how to color based on one column, but not two for the same layer.

How can I use an icon for a polygon without losing the earlier classification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options, which have different effects on the legend rendering.

Here is one of them:

1) Edit the graduated symbol

[image]

2) Add a centroid fill. Click the `+` icon, select the new style, set the `symbol layer type` to `centroid fill`.

It will create a `centroid fill / marker / simplemarker` style.

[image]

3) Click the `simplemarker`. Under `symbol layer type`, select `SVG marker`.

Below `svg group`, click the epsilon button to the right, select `edit`

[image]

Based on the `yesno` column value, use one SVG or the other. Enter the full path to your file. Click OK.

```
if("yesno"=1,'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./svg/accommodation/accommodation_bed_and_breakfast.svg','C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./svg/accommodation/accommodation_alpinehut.svg')
```

4) IF the SVG you are using can have its color customized, you need to use a fixed color else it will be set to the same color as the polygon (i.e. it won't be visible):

Near the top of the SVG Marker panel, click on the epsilon button near Fill Color, select `edit`

Enter a constant color, like `'black'` or a color code. Click ok.

5) Back to the graduated layer styling, classify again the data. The new symbol (color + icon) will be set to each class

[image]